# Wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 1 while extracting with regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have columns in my dataframe (~2 milion rows) that look like this:

```
column
1/20/1"ADAF"
1/4/551BSSS
1/2/1AAAA
1/565/1 "AAA="
```

And I want to extract only:

```
1/20/1
1/4/551
1/2/1
1/565/1
```

I have tried with:

```
df['wanted_column'] = df['column'].str.extract(r'((\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+))', expand=True)
```

But I got an error:

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 1
```

Anyone knows where I am wrong? And if there is a better and faster solution for this, I would be thankful for a suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you want to extract a single part of a string into a single column**, make sure your regex only contains a single capturing group. Remove all other capturing groups (if they are redundant) or convert them into non-capturing ones (if they are used as simple groupings for pattern sequences, e.g. `(\W+\w+){0,3}` -> `(?:\W+\w+){0,3}`).

Here, you can use

```py
df['wanted_column'] = df['column'].str.extract(r'(\d+/\d+/\d+)', expand=True)
```

The point is to only use a **single capturing group** in the regex when you use it with `str.extract` to extract a value into a *single* column.

**Mind**  that `r'((\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+))'` could be also re-written as `r'((?:\d+)/(?:\d+)/(?:\d+))'` for this use case, but these non-capturing groups would be redundant as they only group a single `\d+` pattern in each of them, which makes no sense.

**If you need to extract values into several columns**, mind that the column number should be equal to the amount of capturing groups in the pattern, e.g.

```py
df[['Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3']] = df['column'].str.extract(r'(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)', expand=True)
#       1       2       3                                 ^ 1 ^ ^ 2 ^ ^ 3 ^
```